# Options for multiplayer game server for desktop and mobile

Tags: flash, mobile, desktop, ip

I am looking to create a multiplayer game for both mobile devices (iPhone, Android, etc) and desktops. I have been looking at creating the game in Flash for desktops and writing the game in native language on the mobile device. Does anyone know of a good multiplayer socket server that work for connecting both the mobile and the desktop applications together.

I have looked into SmartFoxServer (had a lot of trouble getting that working for some reason) and red5. If anyone has any alternative or insight into creating a multiplayer game for both desktop and mobile that would be great.

The game would be realtime and not turn based if that makes a difference.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yup, i had a great experience with Skiller's Multiplayer game server. Skiller gives you an SDK that you can connect and create a multiplayer games, from my experience it's real easy and they give you online help. (Skiller's Website: http://dev.skiller-games.com) 
I have combined this SDK capability with the AndEngine (2D physics engine) and created a very impressive multiplayer game. (andEngine's Website: http://www.andengine.org/) 
I think those two are a very good place to start.